# On Simply-Connected

Tags: connectedness, polyhedra

I'm reading Regular Polytopes by H.S.M.Coxeter and have a question about simple-connectedness.

Coxeter says on p.1 (and similarly on p.9) that being simply-connected means that 'every simple closed curve drawn in the region can be shrunk to a point without leaving the region, i.e. there are no holes.'  Then that such simply connected polyhedra satisfy Euler's formula, $N_0-N_1+N_2=2$.

My question regards solids which are composed of two polyhedra joined at a vertex, e.g.[image]

Euler's formula fails for this solid, not surprisingly given that the formula applies to the original two tetrahedron separately, and so before being joined the total number of vertices minus edges plus faces equals four, so combining two vertices into one makes $V-E+F=3$.  It seems to me that any simple closed curve drawn on the solid can be shrunk to a point however - either to the central joining point, or if necessary to one side of the solid.  Am I wrong in thinking this, or are such solids just ruled out for some other reason (I notice that a solid like the above is mentioned by Lakatos in Proofs and Refutations p. 16 and David Richeson in Euler's Gem p.149, albeit the latter adds that 'it is debatable whether these figures should be classified as polyhedra').

Is there a simple way to rule out such solids?  I notice that Coxeter gives as an alternate definition of simple-connectedness that 'every circuit of edges bounds a region' (p.9) which seems to me to be equivalent, but maybe rules out a solid such as the above?

Comment: "Simple connectedness" does make sense for a larger class of objects than polyhedra, and the compound solid you ask about is indeed simply-connected. That compound is not, however, a polyhedron in the usual sense: some condition about the way a vertex is surrounded by faces should fail for the common vertex. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Many thanks - yes, that's what I'm asking.  It sounds like the correct thing to say is that it's simply-connected, but doesn't contradict what Coxeter says because there are reasons for not calling it a polyhedron, e.g., as you say, vertices not surrounded by polygons or similar.  Thanks for clarifying / confirming this.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Just to confirm that you're totally right - Coxeter says on p. 4 'with the proviso that the polygons surrounding each vertex form a single circuit' saying this is added specifically to exclude cases such as the one I mentioned.  I must have skimmed over this when I first read it / maybe thought it was obvious and then forgot it!  Thanks again for your reply.

Comment: Glad to hear you've resolved the matter! <> Reading mathematics tends to be like that: There are all manner of technical conditions whose significance becomes apparent only later. There are times when one needs a succinct term such as _function_ when one really means _a continuous, real-valued function defined on a closed, bounded interval of real numbers_, and the easiest expository action is to make an agreement with the reader that "For the moment, _function_ means ...." <> Anyway, your question is a good one.